# Autosizing collectionview cell not proper display with minimum line space

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, autosize

I have autosize cell collection view in which i need to show data horizontally. All working fine but i need to put 5px spacing between two cell so `minimumLineSpacing` property and problem started **My last cell not properly display because of line spacing. Here is the image**
[image]

Here is the code

```
extension TopicVC : UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 5.0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: HastagCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! HastagCell
        let index = indexPath.row % arrClrFollowTopic.count
        cell.btnHashTag.backgroundColor = Color.custom(hexString: arrClrFollowTopic[index], alpha: 1.0).value
        if indexPath.row % 3 == 0
        {
            cell.btnHashTag.setTitle(strTitle: "#Testing 123545")
        }
        else
        {
            cell.btnHashTag.setTitle(strTitle: "#Testing")
        }
        return cell;
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }
}
```

> ViewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.objCollectionView.register(HastagCell.nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: HastagCell.identifier)



        if let collectionViewLayout = self.objCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout{
            collectionViewLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize.init(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
        }

        self.objCollectionView.delegate = self
        self.objCollectionView.dataSource = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

> My Cell design with autolayout

[image]

> Collectionview layout design

[image]

Comment: Check this out : https://github.com/ElaWorkshop/TagListView

Comment: @ShivamTripathi but i dont want to use third party for just this kind of problem

Comment: take a look at their code might be u will get something.

Comment: @ShivamTripathi this is not suit with my requirement because it is not scrollable

Comment: Hello chirag can i get the code about how u did autosize cell collection

Comment: @bikashgiri sure let me give sometime i need to find that code

Comment: @chiragshah waiting for that code :)

Comment: @bikashgiri i am sorry for forgot this. I follow this article : https://medium.com/@wasinwiwongsak/uicollectionview-with-autosizing-cell-using-autolayout-in-ios-9-10-84ab5cdf35a2

Comment: @chiragshah I'm experiencing the same issue. Did you find an appropriate solution?

Comment: @RTasche this is bug from apple so you need to put some more space at right/left side of cell

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the minimumInteritemSpacing value of your layout to the same as minimumLineSpacing.

So add :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 5
}
```

Comment: it is not necessary to set both thing same never mention any where and i found the issue it is apple bugs.

Comment: Well i did the same and for me it was the solution. You can be sure there is not Apple bugs on this things ...

Comment: Although such a requirement does not seem to be documented anywhere it did the trick in my case.

Comment: yeah, this worked for me too this is weird

Comment: Strange but it worked for me as well. Looks like this is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

**Everything is Right You Missed Only One thing**

Add this `collectionViewLayout` Delegate method for resolve it.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 48))

    label.text = "Your tag text"
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(14) // Set Font whatever you want
    label.sizeToFit()

    return CGSize(width: label.frame.size.width + 16, height: 40)

}
```

or **Try this**

```
cell.layoutSubviews()
cell.setNeedsLayout()
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Add this in `cellForItemAt indexPath` before return the cell

Comment: autosize does not required this method it will calculate the height base on text. here is the link https://medium.com/@wasinwiwongsak/uicollectionview-with-autosizing-cell-using-autolayout-in-ios-9-10-84ab5cdf35a2

Comment: @chiragshah this method also returns the width of the label. or try which one that Added in Updated Answer.

Comment: i have no issue to try this method but the problem is that height of cell will be fix which i do not want

Comment: @chiragshah try this one collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true if not set.